# Single instance AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Let's Encrypt certificate mismatch error

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, certbot

I have a single instance (no load-balancer) Node.js Elastic Beanstalk app that I'm trying to secure with SSL. The app uses Apache as a proxy. I'm configuring everything trough the command line (not using .ebextensions at the moment).

Here's what I did:

1. Assigned a domain (p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar) for the EB app (an alias for the EB app default domain) using AWS Route53
2. Created a VirtualHost file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`
3. Generated a certificate for the domain with `certbot-auto --apache -d p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar`

Although the certificate get's installed and a secured VirtualHost file  `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf` gets created, the certificate is invalid due to a mismatch error. The domain for which the certificate was created for doesn't match the domain that I assigned with Route53.

Certbot says that I should check the SSL certificate analysis here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar

As you can see, the certificate is being generated for the domain `ip-172-31-43-187` and some alternative domains, none of which is the one that I specified in step 3.

What is going on? Why certbot is genereting a certificate for those domains?

Here's my `vhost.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar:80>

    ServerName p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/
</Location>
```

And this is the `vhost-le-ssl.conf` generated by certbot:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar:443>

    ServerName p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/
    </Location>
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/p10-bus-hotel.travelpaq.com.ar/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```